# ABP - LocalIocManager not found for unit test

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, abp, nsubstitute

In aspnet boilerplate, a `LocalIocManager` property was available for unit tests to allow to replace a service and then get the instance we wanted to test with only the dependencies required by the test mocked up by `NSubstitute`.

In abp.io, I cant find this attribute anymore or a replacement procedure. How can I replace it?

In https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Testing#example-testing-a-domain-service-1, we can see an example with a `fakeRepo`, but it is injected "by hand". Doing so can be done when there are few dependencies, but become problematic when there are more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution:
I need to override AfterAddApplication so I have access to `IServiceCollection`.

```cs
protected override void AfterAddApplication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    base.AfterAddApplication(services);

    var fakeRepo = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
    fakeRepo.GetList().Returns(Task.FromResult(new List<Guid>()));

    services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(IMyRepository), _ => fakeRepo));
}
```

However, this will force me to use the same substitute for all my tests. I can't have different instances for each tests.